# Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-settings

I'm currently trying to make a dating app, my first project from scratch. I downloaded a sample project to use as a reference and I want to fire it up on my local server and see what the actual website looks like so I can play around with it and understand the code better. However, after running downloading it through a zip file and then trying to run it on buy local server I get. When I go to the site, I get;

Exception Value:
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Here is a link to the project and also settings.py

project- https://github.com/TheCodingCrusader/Django_Tinder

here is my **settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '8-jze0w4ek6d+d1_tdij96dg5xk299d4etey_p=qrg^2dh+58e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #mine
    'registration',
    'app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'music_tinder.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'music_tinder.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage' 
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage' 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'



STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
```

**original projects settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'u)-vf#0bv3!3)g-58(pox4_^-o$m8#5%idk3bmegowsimy%6)l'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'registration',
    'app',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'music_tinder.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'music_tinder.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

#DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite3://...')
#DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
#DATA
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.parse('sqlite3://...', conn_max_age=600)


#import dj_database_url
#DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

#STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'faketinder'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_KEY']
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 's3.amazonaws.com/' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage' 
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage' 

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)

AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Access-Control-Allow_Origin' : '*'
}

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
```

**views.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from . import forms
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from . import models
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
import os
from django.core import serializers
import json

@login_required
def index(request):
    try:
        user = (User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
    except IndexError:
        user = None
    print (User.username)
    try:
        bio = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user).bio
    except models.UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        create = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
        return redirect('profile')

    friend = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user).friends.all()
    context = dict(user = user, friend = friend)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def create_vote(request, user_id, vote):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    models.UserVote.objects.create(
        user = user,
        voter = request.user,
        vote = vote
    )
    return redirect('index')

@login_required
def nice(request, user_id):
    return create_vote(request, user_id, True)

@login_required
def nope(request, user_id):
    return create_vote(request, user_id, False)

@login_required
def profile(request):
    info = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    user = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    name = info.first_name
    last = info.last_name
    email = info.email
    bio = user.bio
    website = user.website
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            if request.POST['first_name'] != name:
                info.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            else:
                info.name = name

            if request.POST['last_name'] != last:
                info.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            else:
                info.last = last

            if request.POST['email'] != email:
                info.email = request.POST['email']
            else:
                info.email = email

            if request.POST['bio'] != bio:
                user.bio = request.POST['bio']
            else:
                user.bio = bio

            if request.POST['website'] != website:
                user.website = request.POST['website']
            else:
                user.bio = bio

            if len(request.FILES) != 0:
                user.photo = request.FILES['image']

            if info.check_password(request.POST['password']) ==True:
                if request.POST['new_password'] != "":
                    info.set_password(request.POST['new_password'])
            info.save()
            user.save()
    context = dict(info=info, user = user)
    return render(request, "profile.html", context)

def create_vote(request, user_id, vote):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    models.UserVote.objects.create(
        user=user,
        voter=request.user,
        vote=vote
    )
    if vote:
        if models.UserVote.objects.filter(
            user = request.user,
            voter=user,
            vote=True
        ).count():
            npm = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            npm.friends.add(User.objects.get(username=user.username))

            npm = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
            npm.friends.add(User.objects.get(username=request.user))

            npm.save()
            return render(request, 'match.html', dict(
                match=user,
            ))
    return redirect('index')

def network(request):
    friend = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user).friends.all()
    context = dict(friend = friend)
    return render(request, 'network.html', context)
```

Comment: How did you pull down the code? There should be a file named `dj_database_url.py` somewhere.

Comment: can you show the output of pip install dj-database-url

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik.  I just downloaded a zip file. I went through it very carefully and I didn't see that file.  Here is a link to the project on git. https://github.com/TheCodingCrusader/Django_Tinder

Comment: @AjayTomGeorge Ok I just did that and now I am getting this error.                               "raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'

Answer (score 0):

'DATABASE_URL' is not defined in settings.py, default is fetched from user variable which i dont think you have configured`default=os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])`

Since he hasn't given you the DBConfigration details, you cannot fire it up and tinker with it. What u can do see is to create a new project and copy the views, models, urls.py and start it fresh

Comment: I tried all 3 of them and I'm getting the same error for each;      'NameError: name 'dj_database_url' is not defined'

Comment: make sure you python manage.py migrate, before using runserver. You wont get full functionally unless with DATABASE_URL

Comment: I tried that, but it's still giving me the same name error. Also, I didn't create a virtual environment for this project, I just downloaded in a zip file with the current data base. Could that have anything to do with the errors?

Comment: The issue is simply because you haven't configured all settings as it is required and there is no proper readme for the project. I edited the answer, First remove both lines and run manage.py migrate. If it is working. It will use your local db.

Comment: else replace it with last two lines. from the code he is using azure SQL and AWS, of which he hasnt shared the data. So You cant just fire it up and play with. Just edit your settings.py to use sqlite3 and remove aws but it is definitely an extra task.

Comment: In simple he hasn't given you the DBConfigration details. What u can do see is to create a new project and copy the views, models and start it fresh

Comment: Ok, after going through it a bunch and fixing bugs, it's running on the server and I was able to make a database locally and create a super user, however when I try to go to the home page, I get this error 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of'.  I went and edited my question and posted both settings.py  mine and original projects. Would of have been easier to just create a virtual environment for the original project and pip install the requirements?

Comment: Ok now I'm at....       Exception Value: 
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable'.      something to do with one of the views dealing with network